# Converting XY Position Notation to Spreadsheet Position Notation

Tags: python

I want to know how to convert XY position notation (XYPN) into Spreadsheet Position Notation (SPN). For example, I input (15, 3) and it outputs "P3". I have written a SPN->XYPN function in python, although I'm at a loss for the reverse conversion. Here's the code I have so far:

```
import math

def toCartesian(spreadsheetCoords):
    """Takes spreadsheet coordinates (A1, DI113, etc) and
        and turns them into XY coordinates that start at 0, 0"""
    x, y = 0, 0
    xlist = []
    ychars = ""
    for char in spreadsheetCoords:
        if isChar(char):
            xlist.append(indexInAlphabet(char))
        elif isNumber(char):
            ychars = ychars + char
        else:
            print "Error, invalid value inputted"

    cnt = 0
    for i in range(len(xlist)-1, -1, -1):
        x = x + math.pow(26, cnt)*xlist[i]
        cnt += 1
    y = int(ychars)

    return int(x)-1, y-1

def toSpreadsheetCoords(pos):
    return None


#==========[Util]==========#

def isNumber(char):
    if ord(char) >= 48 and ord(char) <= 57:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def isChar(char):
    if ord(char) >= 65 and ord(char) <= 90:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def indexInAlphabet(char):
    return 26-(90-ord(char))

def charAtIndex(i):
    return chr(65+i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it based on the utility functions in the [XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) module.

```
def xl_rowcol_to_cell(row_num, col_num):

    # Removed these 2 lines if your row, col is 1 indexed.
    row_num += 1
    col_num += 1

    col_str = ''

    while col_num:
        remainder = col_num % 26

        if remainder == 0:
            remainder = 26

        # Convert the remainder to a character.
        col_letter = chr(ord('A') + remainder - 1)

        # Accumulate the column letters, right to left.
        col_str = col_letter + col_str

        # Get the next order of magnitude.
        col_num = int((col_num - 1) / 26)

    return col_str + str(row_num)

print xl_rowcol_to_cell(3, 15) # print P4
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I slightly modified this code to do what I want, and it works really well now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://python-excel.org may be at great help for you and especially [`def rowcol_to_cell()`](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/xlwt/Utils.py#L63). They are dealing with excel spreadsheets rather well.

Comment: Thanks, this was good response for showing me what to do next!